# URL entire content to image using HTML Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any way to create an image based on a site URL on the fly?

I wanna make a preview feature where you choose a site in a select box and it shows the site as an image.

I tried using IFrames and Object tags, but I was unable to make the entire content fit to the desired size (Perhaps I missed something?)

So maybe if there's a way (PHP Plugin?) to create an image (**NOT PDF)** based on a URL I would like to hear about it.

**EDIT:**
I am trying to avoid 3rd party API which can easily be found in google search.

Comment: search on google with this key word `php create image of web page` you will find a lot of solutions

Comment: I found quite a few PHP solutions but I would like to hear other options as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are several services that do what you want, like:

- [urlbox](https://urlbox.io/)
- [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com/)
- [page2images](http://www.page2images.com/)

Comment: Trying to avoid using 3rd party API here, but I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Marty do you know of a open source code library I can use?

Comment: @DalaiLama I'm not sure you can go without third party hardware - fairly certain there needs to be a physical machine running that can open the URL and take a capture of what you ask it to, then send that image back.

Comment: I do not mind doing it on my own server, I just can't find the right tech to do it.

Comment: @DalaiLama What I mean is, I'm pretty sure there is a lot more involved than some PHP on your own server. You need a machine dedicated to taking a URL, loading up some custom software to open the URL & take a capture, and then send back the result.

Comment: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf uses the wkhtmltopdf (which also does images). Pretty easy to install on the cl and test out.